# Bluetooth boot error

Tags: bluetooth

I'm getting this error on boot:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -16
```

When I try to turn on the bluetooth, it just stays like this and nothing happens:

[image]

My ubuntu version is 22.04.2.

Edit:
I found a partial solution: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486644, the boot error isn't showing up anymore but I still can't turn on the bluetooth.

Results of `lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep-i 'blue|firm'`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0408:a061 Quanta Computer, Inc. HD User Facing
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 25a7:fa0f Areson Technology Corp 2.4G Wireless Receiver
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:875b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. AQIRYS Alya Wireless Headset
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3801 Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa70 Areson Technology Corp 2.4G Wireless Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.129384] Spectre V2 : Enabling Speculation Barrier for firmware calls
[    0.289020] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.305297] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    3.321977] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.322033] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.322034] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.322042] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.322046] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.322051] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.452059] mt7615e 0000:04:00.0: N9 Firmware Version: 3.1.1, Build Time: 20200604161656
[    4.741694] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0101001F
[    4.747560] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.16 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 3
[    4.747602] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    6.569521] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.569526] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.569530] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep-i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @Jeremy31 done.

Comment: Can you try `bluetoothctl` and then do `power on`

Comment: it returned: `No default controller available`

Comment: See if anything changes after `sudo modprobe btusb`

Comment: What result for `mokutil --sb` if secure boot is enabled the fixed btusb module won't load

Comment: Secure boot is enabled, do I have to disable it, if so, how :)

Comment: nevermind, I found out how, after disabling the SecureBoot, `sudo modprobe btusb` command worked and even `bluetoothctl` + `power on`, now I can turn on the bluetooth, but is it good to keep SecureBoot disabled?

Comment: The fix won't work with Secure Boot enabled unless you use mokutil and that might be more work than it is worth